# Asynchronous process reading cannot read prompt

Tags: c#, asynchronous, process, prompt

I'm working on a simple wrapper for an existing application to automate it by asynchronously reading and responding to it's prompts.

The asynchronous reading is done by using `Process.BeginOutputReadLine` and `Process.BeginErrorReadLine`, and here's the catch:

The events for reading returns only once a full line is read, so when user input is expected, the prompt is not returned and the program hangs. How can I read the prompt even though it's not a full line? Can I even detect when the program expects user input?

Comment: It's no surprise that `BeginOutputReadLine` is line-buffered. You may need to use the synchronous `.Read()` instead.

Comment: You'll need to contact the owner of the program and ask for a code change.  One line needs to be added, fflush(stdout); after the line of code that outputs the prompt.  Which ensures that the prompt is flushed out of output buffer.

Comment: istepaniuk, before i consider reimplementing this as synchronous, how can I know how much I can `.Read()`? Won't it block me as well if it's waiting for user input? Hans Passant, I rather not modify the application. If I choose to change it, why would I need a wrapper in the first place?\